# working with asynctask and json parsing simultaneously between two activities

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I need some suggestion on how to go about this specific android problem: 
  activity A passes an intent to activity B,
  B reads it, makes an API call,
  B receives response, parses it, and updates its views from the response

now it works fine except fr a 2  second black screen during transition from A to B
is asynctask a solution? becoz the parsing data is not much and also is there a way to update UI views frm asynctask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To echo what Lalit said, an AsyncTask will help in this case.  The problem that you're having is that doing the API call during `onCreate` is blocking the activity from updating the UI.  If you use an AsyncTask, it will allow the activity to continue rendering the view.

As you're parsing the result, you can update the UI by calling `Activity.runOnUiThread()` or by putting the UI code in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: run on UI thread is not a solution, its similar to writing the code in oncreate, postexecute and preexecute looks organised and works well

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if AsyncTask is the best solution for your case.
An AsyncTask is very helpful if you need to do something in background and allow the user to do something else in the mean time.

I'd sugest to just use a Thread and define a progressDialog.
If you do it this way, your user will see the loading dialog with the spinning circe and not the black screen that looks more like if the App is freezing.

Let me know if you need help with some code samples.
Marco :)

Comment: thanks marco..:) bt u knw wat...i tried that progress dialog in another thread and stuff...bt thr was the problem, screen would go black after showing the dialog...quite iritating fr the user!!